# AWS CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, cdn

I have a Rails app running on ElasticBeanstalk. My app is using SSL certificate from `symantec`. After config my cloudfront, I am getting this error:

`CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.` Following snapshot were my Distribution settings.

[image]

[image]

The CloudFront can display popular objects, but the issues is, I cant access any of those:

[image]

Seriously, There is no solutions on other places. So I believe my question is unique. Thanks!!

Comment: Does it work without HTTPS?  (If not, then most of the rest of this comment won't make sense.) Enable the checkbox for all of the origin SSL protocols.  Also, your SSL cert is installed in your app server?  Does that cert match the domain name in "Origin Domain Name?"  And is origin domain name set to the hostname of the app server?  Can you access the app server using that hostname, with https, using a browser?

Comment: Why is only sslv3 enabled? ssl v3 is usually turned off (because of poodle), so your origin could easily not be accepting the requests from cloudfront.

Comment: @FrederickCheung Already turned off, still not fetching anythg

Comment: you are getting 5xx error codes which means: server error, check your logs on the origin, there's probably something wrong with the configuration, it's hard to say what; it's also kinda weird that favicon.ico is giving a 5xx instead of a 404, perhaps i'm missing something or your origin server is "acting weird"

Comment: is your website public available ? Did you open port 80 in your VPC settings to all IPs?

Comment: you should test if your origin is accessible. Try to do {origin domain name}/favicon.ico for example. I hope you didn't put in www.example.com as shown in your screenshot ;-)